# Chat Jquery AJAX losing messages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, promise

I'm making a call by AJAX and everything works properly in the backend. Just in the frontend doesnt display every message the whole time. I'm also removing/editing messages from admin user profile, but I don't think this issue is coming from that.
To know which messages I should take from the DB I have a column with UNIX date, and this value is stored as HTML id attribute. So, each time the AJAX is sent, I take the last message UNIX date. I think the issue should come related to that, but I don't arive to understand where:

```
function doAjax() {
    let lastMes = $('.pwc_m:first-child').attr('id');//get last UNIX date stored in HTML id attribute
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajaxUrl,
            data: {
                'action': 'refreshChat',
                'url': Url,
                'last': lastMes
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                if($(response)[2] == 'md' || $(response)[2] == 'rm'){
                    //A message to modify
                    if($(response)[2] == 'md'){
                        $('#' + $(response)[1].fecha).find('p:last-child').html('<span class="modified">' + $(response)[1].mensaje + '</span>')

                        $(response[0]).each(function(){
                            $('.text').prepend('<div id="' + $(this)[0].fecha + '" class="pwc_m"><div class="clicker"><div class="chat_edit_element">e</div></div><div><span>' + $(this)[0].username + '</span></div><p>' + $(this)[0].mensaje + '</p></div>');
                        });
                    }else if($(response)[2] == 'rm'){
                        $('#' + $(response)[1].fecha).find('p:last-child').html('<span class="removed">' + AJAX.Removed + '</span>')

                        $(response[0]).each(function(){
                            $('.text').prepend('<div id="' + $(this)[0].fecha + '" class="pwc_m"><div class="clicker"><div class="chat_edit_element">e</div></div><div><span>' + $(this)[0].username + '</span></div><p>' + $(this)[0].mensaje + '</p></div>');
                        });
                    }
                }else{
                    //Nothing to modify
                    $(response).each(function(){
                        if($(this)[0].mensaje == AJAX.Removed){
                            $('.text').prepend('<div id="' + $(this)[0].fecha + '" class="pwc_m"><div class="clicker"><div class="chat_edit_element">e</div></div><div><span>' + $(this)[0].username + '</span></div><p><span class="removed">' + AJAX.Removed + '</span></p></div>');
                        }else{
                            $('.text').prepend('<div id="' + $(this)[0].fecha + '" class="pwc_m"><div class="clicker"><div class="chat_edit_element">e</div></div><div><span>' + $(this)[0].username + '</span></div><p>' + $(this)[0].mensaje + '</p></div>');
                        }
                    }); 
                }
            }/* ,
            complete: function(){
                setTimeout(doAjax, 500);
            } */
    }).promise().done(
        setTimeout(doAjax, 1000)
        );
}
```